# Naming function call after variable assignment

Tags: javascript

I have unusual problem.

I don't know how to put into words given operations in JavaScript example.

```
var FunctionLayer2 = FunctionLayer1(2);  //How to put into words this variable assignment and calling FunctionLayer1()

FunctionLayer2(4); //How to put into words calling function from the created variable with output based on the argument from previous call

function FunctionLayer1 (value1) {

    console.log(value1);

    return (function (value2) {
        console.log(value2*value1);
    })
}
```

Sorry for this unusual question but i have found about this functionality recently and couldn't find much about it before.

Comment: The term you are wanting is "Currying"

Comment: `FunctionLayer1` and `FunctionLayer2` are already bad names. Name them to explain what they do

Comment: How to name things is off-topic on stack overflow

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but the pattern you've described has a few possible names. Either ["Currying"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) or maybe ["Partial Application"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)

Comment: This question is duplicated, i faced almost 3 questions like this in week ago and all with different titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patter you are trying to use is called `currying`. This is when you return a function from another function.

```
function sample(str){
  return function(anotherStr){
    return str + '' + anotherStr
  }
}

var foo = sample('Hello')
var result = foo('StackOverflow')
console.log(result) // 'Hello StackOverflow'
```

your case:

```
function multiply(x){
  return function(y){
    return x * y
  }
}

var multiply3 = multiply(3)
var multiply3By4 = multiply3(4)
console.log(multiply3By4) // 12
```

[`Here`](https://medium.com/@kbrainwave/currying-in-javascript-ce6da2d324fe) is a blog with a simple examples & description about `currying` so it might be useful for you